# Array.find(value) return value 'is not a function'

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm trying to use JavaScript's `find()` function on an AngularJS array.  That's legal, right...?

This very simple code is causing me some problems.  It's saying that the return value from `$scope.names.find(name1)` is not a function.

`TypeError: Name1 is not a function`

```
if($scope.names.find(name1) !== name1) {
   $scope.names.push(name1);
}
```

I have also tried...

```
if($scope.names.find(name1) === undefined) {
   $scope.names.push(name1);
}
```

and

```
if(!$scope.names.find(name1)) {
   $scope.names.push(name1);
}
```

This `if` is in a loop.  If `name` is not in the array, then add it.  If it is already in the array, don't add it.

Here is the loop:

```
angular.forEach($scope.names1, function (name1) {
    angular.forEach($scope.names2, function (name2) {
        if (name1 === name2) {
            $scope.names.push(name1);
        }
    });
    if ($scope.names.find(name1) === name1) {
        $scope.names.push(name1);
    }
});
```

I don't know what the error is referring to exactly.  I must be misusing [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Comment: As you can see in Docs `find` takes callback function as argument, use `if (!$scope.names.find(function (name1) {
        $scope.names.push(name1);
    })
}`

Comment: No, it's saying `name1` isn't a function.

Comment: `TypeError: name1 is not a function` because `.find` takes a callback function and executes it on array items, and returns the value of an item that satisfies the callback function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: @DaveNewton The error is self-explanatory, it says that the passed parameter is not a function, that means parameter should be a function

Comment: @Tushar Which is precisely what I said.

Comment: @DaveNewton I misunderstood, I thought you're responding to my previous comment, now I understand that you were saying that to OP

Comment: @Tushar Ah, sorry, I see--I posted before I saw your comment. Didn't mean to be snappy, either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `indexOf`. Your snippet would be

```
if($scope.names.indexOf(name1) < 0) { //Value not exists in your array
   $scope.names.push(name1);
}
```

Comment: An index of zero means the element is at the zeroth position and therefore does exist in the array. You can instead do `$scope.names.indexOf(name1) === -1`.

Comment: Or `$scope.names.includes(name1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, consider using  [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)  There are a lot of useful functions including _.find()